# Whats the error in this python code?

Tags: python, session-hijacking

What do i do to solve it?
Terminal output is:

`abhi@abhi-desktop:~/Desktop/sslstrip-0.1$ python sslstrip.py --listen=3130
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sslstrip.py", line 254, in 
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "sslstrip.py", line 246, in main
    server = ThreadingHTTPServer(('', listenPort), StripProxy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 400, in init
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 411, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "", line 1, in bind
TypeError: an integer is required
abhi@abhi-desktop:~/Desktop/sslstrip-0.1$`

Here is a 21kb code given...
[Download link](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/sslstrip-0.5.tar.gz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it fail when you don't specify a port?

My guess is that listenPort is coming out of the option parsing as a string and needs to be cast to an in sslstrip.py on line 77.

Comment: when i dont specify a port, it shows this error..
 File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Comment: @Shadyabhi - that is at least a step closer to working.  What happens if you try a different port numbers (try something high and random, e.g. 10103)

Comment: As i dont know much in python, for the time being, i edited the code and gave the value of listenPort in the code itself instead of giving it through command line... Anyways, thanx for your replies... But, i will still really appreciate the effort to solve the bug

Answer (score 2):

The provided link is to sslstrip-0.5. You are using sslstrip-0.1. These are *very* different (sslstrip-0.5 uses twisted). This bug was fixed in sslstrip-0.2. If you don't have twisted or don't want to install twisted, I suggest that you get [sslstrip-0.4](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/sslstrip-0.4.tar.gz).

Comment: i am sorry.. That was a foolish mistake. The actual link is: http://code.securitytube.net/sslstrip-0.1.tar.gz

Anyways, the problem in both the versions remain the same.